# Making a promotional video for a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, videos

Over on the [Genealogy & Family History site](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/), we are exploring possible ways to expand our user base. We have had the [idea to create a short promotional video](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3239/making-a-promotional-video-for-gfh-se) about the site, which could be shared in other online genealogy communities. There are no firm plans yet as to what this video would contain. However, before taking this any further there is a growing list of questions that we need answered:

- First and foremost, can we do this?
- Has this been done by a Stack Exchange site before? If it has, it would be good to see any previous promo videos to get some ideas.
- Would our status as a beta site have any impact on whether this could be implemented?
- Could video or still screen shots of the Stack Exchange site be included?
- What are the necessary permissions or approvals that would need to be obtained from Stack Exchange? This obviously will depend somewhat on the content, but are there any general guidelines?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270574/an-experiment-stack-overflow-tv

Comment: Not really promotional but worth mentioning are the introductionary training videos from [Kate Gregory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147247/kate-gregory) over on Pluralsight: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites

Comment: @rene In that Q, there's a comment on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270584/4023846: "Creating smaller videos that can be replayed, and putting them somewhere that new users that are confused and want to learn better how to use SO can watch them."  Kate's course is interesting but what we'd like is something like a customized tour that showcased Genealogy.SE specifically. Ideally, I'd like to show *how to ask a good question* because that's something newbies struggle with.

Comment: How would you distribute it in a way that didn't make it feel unsolicited (which runs the risk of people associating SE in general with spam)? I don't think I've ever actually seen an SE ad *anywhere* off site before, which was always a good thing, to me anyways.

Comment: [Esperanto Stack Exchange (with English subtitles)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qPry_esR3Q) is one of several YouTube videos about ... Esperanto Stack Exchange!